# Qt and DESTDIR being ignored?

Tags: qt, macos

My app folder is "app"
It contains both .pro and source files
It has a "bin" folder.

the "DESTDIR = bin\" in my .pro file

however, when building from Qt-Creator, a sibling folder is being created, called "app-build-desktop" and the binaries are stored there under a new "bin" folder.

why is this happening? why is another sibling folder being created and hosts a new bin folder instead of just creating the binary file in my existing "bin" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Projects" area (on the left pane of Qt Creator) there is a "Shadow build" option in the Build Settings. You can uncheck this to disable it.

That being said, it is a useful feature, for example for keeping your actual source directory clean of temporary files that you have to ignore in source control.

Comment: yeah. found it. it kind of makes sense I guess. I'll just start a deeper tree structure and have my source, project and binary folders as siblings.

BTW: it will not even allow to define an output folder that's within the source folder. It actually comments about it in QT-Creator if you try.